# How to move file from on folder to another folder as a different user?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, shutil

how to move file from on folder to another folder as a different user.

I am general user I don't have write access, hence I cant write or modify or paste any file in specific folder (`C:\test`).

If I login as admin user I can write or modify or paste the files in (`C:\test`)

I wanted to write python code which can do this activity.

I tried, `shutil` but not help following is my code:

```
shutil.move(source+f, dest1)
```

Could someone help to paste file from one folder to another folder as a different user?

Comment: Why not run the script as the other user?

Comment: If you don't have permissions then there is nothing you can do about it with that user.

Comment: its privilege user we all don't have the access of it.